# CSV to sequence? "TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set". How to fix it.

Tags: python

I am trying to follow this code http://alexminnaar.com/time-series-classification-and-clustering-with-python.html for doing time series clustering; when I try to follow the example in order to start understanding how it works, I get this error:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import random

def k_means_clust(data,num_clust,num_iter,w=5):
    centroids=random.sample(data,num_clust)
    counter=0
    for n in range(num_iter):
        counter+=1
        #print counter
        assignments={}
        #assign data points to clusters
        for ind,i in enumerate(data):
            min_dist=float('inf')
            closest_clust=None
            for c_ind,j in enumerate(centroids):
                if LB_Keogh(i,j,5)<min_dist:
                    cur_dist=DTWDistance(i,j,w)
                    if cur_dist<min_dist:
                        min_dist=cur_dist
                        closest_clust=c_ind
            if closest_clust in assignments:
                assignments[closest_clust].append(ind)
            else:
                assignments[closest_clust]=[]

        #recalculate centroids of clusters
        for key in assignments:
            clust_sum=0
            for k in assignments[key]:
                clust_sum=clust_sum+data[k]
            centroids[key]=[m/len(assignments[key]) for m in clust_sum]

    return centroids

train = np.genfromtxt('datasets/train.csv', delimiter='\t')
test = np.genfromtxt('datasets/test.csv', delimiter='\t')
data=np.vstack((train[:,:-1],test[:,:-1]))

import matplotlib.pylab as plt

centroids=k_means_clust(data,4,10,4)
for i in centroids:

    plt.plot(i)

plt.show()
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- **TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()**
>         5 import matplotlib.pylab as plt
>         6 
>   ----> 7 centroids=k_means_clust(data,4,10,4)
>         8 for i in centroids:
>         9
>
> in k_means_clust(data, num_clust,
>   num_iter, w)
>         2 
>         3 def k_means_clust(data,num_clust,num_iter,w=5):
>   ----> 4     centroids=random.sample(data,num_clust)
>         5     counter=0
>         6     for n in range(num_iter):
>
> C:\Users\Luis\Anaconda3\lib\random.py in sample(self, population, k)
>       309             population = tuple(population)
>       310         if not isinstance(population, _Sequence):
>   --> 311             raise TypeError("Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).")
>       312         randbelow = self._randbelow
>       313         n = len(population)
>
> **> TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use
>   list(d).**

```
This is the data I am loading:


[[-0.37693558  1.2248643   0.34387438 ...,  0.91834602 -1.3117417
  -1.1971462 ]
 [ 0.64440621  0.41326914 -0.86227849 ...,  1.3981403   0.08574208
   0.02499741]
 [-0.97866735 -0.40623244  0.82242857 ...,  0.66612895  0.10699555
   0.08271546]
 ..., 
 [ 0.8455511   0.05714152  1.2228095  ..., -0.51199761 -0.86978484
  -0.2057573 ]
 [ 1.9725294   0.41645028  1.6845052  ..., -1.3956278  -1.0317821
  -1.1345864 ]
 [ 1.5162553   1.1602023   1.2666022  ..., -0.85115838 -0.85573754
  -1.0178208 ]]
```

***Should I convert that to a sequence? How should I fix it?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[SciPy]: numpy.vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html#numpy-vstack) returns an [[SciPy]: numpy.ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html#numpy-ndarray), 
while [[Python]: random.**sample**(*population, k*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) expects a sequence ([[Python]: *class* collections.abc.**Sequence**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence))

**Example**:

> ```
> >>> import sys
> >>> import random
> >>> import numpy as np
> >>>
> >>> "Python {:s} on {:s}".format(sys.version, sys.platform)
> 'Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32'
> >>>
> >>> a = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
> >>> b = np.array([[2], [3], [4]])
> >>> data = np.vstack((a, b))
> >>> data
> array([[1],
>        [2],
>        [3],
>        [2],
>        [3],
>        [4]])
> >>> random.sample(data, 4)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\lib\random.py", line 320, in sample
>     raise TypeError("Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).")
> TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).
> >>> random.sample(data.tolist(), 4)
> [[3], [4], [2], [3]]
> ```

**Fix**:

Use `numpy.ndarray.tolist()`. In your code, replace

```
centroids=random.sample(data,num_clust)
```

by

```
centroids = random.sample(data.tolist(), num_clust)
```

or use `list(data)` (as the exception text instructs (for `dict`s)).

Answer (score 1):

In the function:

```
   def k_means_clust(data,num_clust,num_iter,w=5):
       centroids=random.sample(data,num_clust)
```

you are using random on a numpy array: 
The random library does not work with numpy arrays, so what you can do, is to convert the numpy array into a list:

```
   def k_means_clust(data,num_clust,num_iter,w=5):
       centroids=random.sample(list(data),num_clust)
```